# How to echo a message in BufWritePost so that it writes over the "~/.foo xxxL, xxC written" status message?

Tags: autocmd

Say I write an autocommand for a particular file to do something when I save it, such as

```
autocmd BufWritePost .Xresources silent! execute 'xrdb ~/.Xresources'
```

I'm doing it with `silent! execute`, because if I only use

`autocmd BufWritePost .Xresources !xrdb ~/.Xresources`

vim would prompt for an enter. But I still want to see that the reload happened, which I thought could be handled with `echo`, such as

```
autocmd BufWritePost .Xresources silent! execute 'xrdb ~/.Xresources' | echo 'Xresources reloaded'
```

But again this has the problem of prompting to `Press ENTER or type command to continue`. Now there is `echon` which does not do prompt for ENTER, but it also does not display the message, as saving the file with `:w` causes `"~/.Xresources" 487L, 18435C written` to be written to the status line instead.

So the quation is, is there some way to run the autocommand such that it saves the file, runs the shell command, and echoes a confirmation message in the status line, without prompting the user to press ENTER, or interrupt in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the exact behavior you want is achievable. If it is it'll probably involve use of the `:redraw` command (or `Ctrl-L` in Normal mode). I haven't found the magic combo but can propose a couple "workarounds".

If you don't mind having the message displayed for a limited amount of time before it disappears you could try something like

```
<snip> silent! execute 'xrdb ~/.Xresources' | echo 'Xresources reloaded' | sleep 2 | redraw
```

Or, if you don't always need to see the confirmation and just want a way to check it explicitly now and then you could use `echom` and look for the message manually with `:mess` (or `:1mess` if looking for it immediately after the autocommand runs).

```
<yadda yadda> silent! execute 'xrdb ~/.Xresources' | echom 'Xresources reloaded' | redraw
```

Still, I'll see if I can find the ideal solution.

**Edit**: Actually...just swapping the `echo` and `redraw` positions might be the ticket!

```
<yadda yadda> execute 'xrdb ~/.Xresources' | redraw | echo 'Xresources reloaded'
```

Bonus: you might not need `silent` either. I've left it off but if your screen is getting jumpy or something then you can include it. Depends, at least in part, on how much output `xrdb` has.

I don't have `xrdb` and what not so I was faking it with other shell commands so you'll need to verify.

(BTW, are you missing a bang `!` before `xrdb`? Thought it was an external command..)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not missing the ! since `silent! execute` already does that, but anyway, like you mentioned, leaving out `silent!` does not work as both things get shown, but `autocmd BufWritePost .Xresources silent! execute 'xrdb ~/.Xresources' | redraw | echo 'Xresources reloaded'` works perfectly :)

Comment: Hmm. `silent! execute` has no magic that allows you to leave off the `!` before the external command. Are you sure the silent isn't obscuring relevant error messages? :) Anyways, that wasn't the question you asked. Glad one of my solutions works well for you. Cheers!